# how to use float number as opencv image pixel coordinates

Tags: opencv

I have a texture image and some uv coordinators (some float 2D vectors).
Is there any method in OpenCV can automatically interpolate the image and then I can directly use these float number as the pixel coordinator and get the correct pixel value?

I think it should be possible because in some computer vision algorithms like optic flow we will always have some sub pixel value...

Comment: My guess is no since "subpixel value" is not well-defined. (There's a variety interpolation methods.)

Comment: [`remap`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=remap#remap) is probably the closest to what you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Remap](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=remap#remap) is what you want, here is an example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('myimage.png')
interpolated_pixel = cv2.remap(img, np.array([[2.4]], np.float32), np.array([[5.4]], np.float32), cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
print(interpolated_pixel)
```

You can play with different interpolation schemes, see [interpolation flags](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html)

Of course you can also batch your request by providing multiple uv coordinates.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I want exactly. So is this also be used in the implementation of optical flow?

Comment: I'm not sure you would have to look at the source code, but it is definitely used a lot of places, some may not use the API